# how to split a decimal integer into ascii values?

Tags: c

I have a 4 digit decimal number say 1234. I want to split this number into 4 separate ASCII values like '1','2','3','4'.

The process should not include division operation or integer to string conversion etc.

Comment: Oh good -- yet another "I want to do this, but definitely *not* the right way."

Comment: So your question is how to convert an int into a string without converting an int to a string?

Comment: I particularly dislike the "etc"

Comment: @pmg Agreed. I read it as "or anything that possibly does this".

Comment: This sound pretty much like a programming exercise and nothing that you'd do for real. Exercises are there for you to execise, not us.

Comment: `const char * solution = "1234";`

Comment: Division is simply "glorified subtraction" :)

Comment: Count how many times you can subtract 1000 until its < 1000, then the same for 100 and 10.  Those, together with the remainder left at the end, are your 4 decimal digits.  Add `'0'` to each one to convert to ASCII.

Comment: Thank you. I got it. It will help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to extract each digit of the number and add '0'. If this is against your requirements, feel free to ignore.

Answer (score 1):

you can anytime change division operator subtraction anytime.

Comment: ***"The process should not include division operation"***.

Comment: Hi, Sorry for 'etc'. But this is not an exercise. This is a very important issue. Because I need to run this on a slow speed device like PIC micro controller. I tried to solve this issue using division operation and int to string conversion,but both are taking too much time,almost 100 micro seconds. I need faster algorithm. I can't disclose my entire target now. I hope you can answer this.